# How do I extract the private keys from my namecoind wallet?

Tags: private-key, namecoin

Seems like namecoind doesn't support the `dumpprivkey` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools

or pywallet (link on the site above).

These are the only ways I know. Not really comfortable. Also it is probably not possible while namecoind is running.

Comment: Thanks @phelix. It seems that for namecoin, one needs to use a forked version of pywallet https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet and use the command line parameter --namecoin.

Comment: Fun fact: you can even share private keys between Bitcoin and Namecoin. Might make a good secret wallet ;)

Comment: Care to explain? :)

Comment: Bitcoin and Namecoin private and public keys are exactly the same thing. Only the address generated from the pub key looks a little different. It is possible to generate both address types from a single priv key. Check out the casascius address utility.